# Angular 11 Inlining of fonts failed

Tags: angular, angular11

Trying to build angular11 app in a system behind proxy.  When running "ng build --prod" I get this error:

> Inlining of fonts failed. An error has occurred while retrieving
> https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap
> over the internet. getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND fonts.googleapis.com

Some posts said to disable it, directing to this angular doc [URL](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#optimization-configuration) for more info, but I can't get that to work.  If I edit **angular.json** "optimization" parameter to below, I get a **Schema validation failed...Data path .optimization should be boolean** error:

```
"optimization": { 
  "scripts": true,
  "styles": {
    "minify": true,
    "inlineCritical": true
  },
  "fonts": false
}
```

If I follow this [post](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/angular-version-11-is-out-a-comprehensive-look-and-why-you-might-want-update-your-projects-5db652ce110c) (search for "AUTOMATIC FONT INLINING") and add below in **package.json**, it doesn't seem to have any effect:

```
"optimization": { 
  "scripts": true,
  "styles": false,
  "fonts": false
}
```

Comment: Is there any solution on that? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: How did you resolve it ? I'm also facing similar issue.

Comment: Facing the same issue.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Following Angular's guidance on the [URL](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#optimization-configuration) you mentioned, I changed angular.json file only, slightly different way and it worked for me. Here is what I changed in angular.json file under production property.

```
"production": {
    ...
    "optimization": {
        "scripts": true,
         "styles": true,
         "fonts": false
     },
     ...
},
```

Answer (score 11):

According to
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/19848

setting an environment `HTTPS_PROXY` variables does the job. It works for me behind the corporate proxy (don't forget `http://`):

```
SET HTTPS_PROXY=http://<server-name>:<server-port>
ng build
```

Environment: `Windows 10, nodejs v14.17.4, angular 12.2.0`

Comment: do you set them for npm, or vs code, or ng

Comment: I set the environment variable HTTPS_PROXY globally using Windows 10 Control Panel.

Answer (score 3):

i got same error :

[image]

resolved issue after making below changes in index.html file

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Disconnecting from corporate VPN solved this issue for me.

Angular 15

Error :
✖ Index html generation failed.
Inlining of fonts failed. An error has occurred while retrieving https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&display=swap over the internet.
connect ETIMEDOUT 172.208.21.111:443

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the suggestions didn't work (except the proxy). So i downloaded css files from google server and binded via angular.json to the sources

```
"styles": [
    "src/styles.scss",
    "src/assets/fonts/roboto.scss",
    "src/assets/fonts/material-icons.scss"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Tried change optimization but did not helped.

Finally I called **'npm audit fix --force'** inside my terminal and that solved my problem.

--force parameter is quite bruteforce here but if you are confident in that command, nothing bad should happened.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a problem with my VPN service.

Comment: If you could give more context that could be helpful for those of us in organizations behind VPN's.

Comment: I really wish I could. It was a personal VPN (express VPN), so I just turned it off, and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The best and simplest solution to this problem without making any change to angular.json.
Simply Save the library Provide a name of your choice and map it to your index.html file as shown below.
It does not required any proxy settings or any changes in angular.json or any change in production property.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/materialIcon.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was caused by the node version 18.x. Reverted back to 16.x LTS and it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer [this](https://appdividend.com/2018/12/25/angular-material-icon-tutorial-with-example/) link.Here instead of referencing the google api link in index.html file, I imported it in style.css file as shown in the given article and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

It's just a style sheet, feel free to remove it from "index.html" (or any pages that links to it):

```
<link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
```

Or you can access the href link to get its content and make that as a new css or copy into the existing ones.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I just deleted node module folder of my project and again install node module
cmd : npm i